# Regex Node in Html

Tags: c#, regex

I want to select node  some text in `<>` signs and change its color...

```
MatchCollection begin = Regex.Matches(richXmlBox.Text, @"\<\b.*\>\b");

if (begin != null && begin.Count > 0)
{
    foreach (Match m in begin)
    {
        richXmlBox.Select(m.Index, m.Length);
        richXmlBox.SelectionColor = Color.Crimson;
    }
}
```

this works for for example this `sdfsdf<something>asd`

but it doesnt work for this `<something><something>`

Comment: Change regex to `@"<[^>]*>"`. But the solution is still very fragile against wild HTML.

Comment: thx for advice but i dont changing HTML but XML i made syntax highlighter in windows forms .. if i copy some XML text to richTextBox its highlight me everything like in MVS the last bug is this i will try that tommorow thx again

Comment: Then use LINQ to XML - use `XDocument`. It would be easier to work with than regex.

Comment: but the result bust be one big string totaly same like XML but with different colors... i dont think XDocument could help me